Reducer Actions in React acts funny
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import PersonAddAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonAddAlt';
import GroupAddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GroupAdd';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from '@mui/material';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContex';
import ChatListItem from './chat/ChatListItem';

const Modal = ({ isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen }) => {
    const [conversationType, setConversationType] = useState("solo")
    const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState("")
    const [authState] = useContext(AuthContext)

    const handleConversationType = (event, type) => {
        setConversationType(type)
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log(authState)
        alert("Hurray convo created!!")
    }
    return (
        <Dialog onClose={() => setIsModalOpen(false)} open={isModalOpen}>
            <h1 className="text-center text-xl py-2">Create conversation</h1>
            <div className='w-[500px] h-[500px] px-3 mt-2 flex flex-col  gap-2 overflow-hidden '>
                <div className='w-full flex justify-center'>
                    <ToggleButtonGroup
                        value={conversationType}
                        exclusive
                        onChange={handleConversationType}
                    >
                        <ToggleButton value="solo">
                            <PersonAddAltIcon />
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ToggleButton value="group">
                            <GroupAddIcon />
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </div>
                {
                    conversationType === "group" &&
                    <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                        <input
                            value={groupName}
                            onChange={(e) => setGroupName(e.target.value)}
                            id="group"
                            type="text"
                            className='outline-none h-10 p-1 '
                            placeholder='What is your group name?' />
                    </div>
                }
                <div className='overflow-y-scroll'>

                    {
                        authState.allUsers.map(user => {
                            return <ChatListItem data={user} key={user.userName} />
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleSubmit} className='bg-green-200 px-1 mx-auto rounded-xl py-2 w-1/2 text-black mb-1 hover:bg-green-400'>Create</button>
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default Modal

ChatListItem.jsx
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import Avatar from '../Avatar'
import { Checkbox } from '@mui/material'
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContex'

const ChatListItem = ({ data, isConversationItem = false }) => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
    const [authState, authDispatch] = useContext(AuthContext)

    const handleCheckBox = (e) => {
        console.log(authState)
        if (e.target.checked) {
            console.log("Here adding checked user")
            authDispatch({
                type: "ADD_CHECKED_USER",
                checkedUser: data
            })
        } else {
            console.log("Nere")
            authDispatch({
                type: "REMOVE_CHECKED_USER",
                checkedUser: data?.userName
            })
        }
        setIsChecked(e.target.checked)
    }
    return (
        <div className='flex cursor-pointer p-1 gap-3 items-center w-full h-14 my-2'>
            <Avatar img={data?.profilePic} />
            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <span className='text-slate-500 font-light text-md'>{data?.fullName || "Loading.."}</span>
                {
                    isConversationItem &&
                    <span className='text-sm'>Lorem ipsum dolor...</span>
                }
            </div>

            {
                !isConversationItem &&
                <Checkbox
                    sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
                    checked={isChecked}
                    onChange={handleCheckBox}
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                />
            }

        </div>
    )
}

export default ChatListItem

AuthReducer.js

export const initalAuthState = {
    userInfo: null,
    conversations: [],
    allUsers: [],
    checkedUsers: []
}

export const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_USER_INFO": {
            return { ...state, userInfo: action.userInfo }
        }
        case "SET_CONVERSATIONS": {
            return { ...state, conversations: action.conversations }
        }
        case "SET_ALL_USERS": {
            return { ...state, allUsers: action.allUsers }
        }
        case "ADD_CHECKED_USER": {
            return {
                ...state, checkedUsers: state?.checkedUsers?.push(action.checkedUser)
            }
        }
        case "REMOVE_CHECKED_USER": {
            return {
                ...state, checkedUsers: state?.checkedUsers?.filter(user => user.userName != action.userName)
            }
        }
        case "RESET_CHECKED_USERS": {
            return { ...state, checkedUsers: [] }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}

This is the workflow -> current user can see a list of users in a modal box to check/uncheck them (basically to create a conversation with them) -> create button is supposed to make an API call in the backend
Each checkbox has an event listener that adds the checked user to the state or remove them from the state.
I am using a combination of context and reducers to manage state in this case.
As you can see I am logging whenever user triggers an onChange event on the checkbox.
I am logging the current state before dispatch action have been called. Under normal scenario, the current state should not have knowledge of which user was checked but in the output as shown below you can see that user is already added before the dispatch function has been called. (see checkedUser)
Also, when I hit the create button, you can see that it somehow converts the array into a number. (checkedUser : 2)
Please help me to debug this. I have tried to log in wherever possible to understand what is causing this effect, but I am not able to understand it.
Output
